# how to import "after effects" animations to android?

Tags: android, jquery-animate, material-design, after-effects

Onetime I saw top 10 material designs in a website. many of them uses "Adobe After Effect" for creating animations. I want to know how to import animations to android project. One other question is : What about jquery? I can import it? how? After Effects is better or jquery?

Comment: any outcome for this?

Comment: now after api 21 sdk's animations is very good and enough in many cases (google SharedElement and Transaction Animation) but other way is to export After Effects animation in gif format and import it in android. I have no idea about jquery but surely After Effects is easier to use and more advanced for this usage.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there's two awesome libraries that let you export a .json file from After Effects, using a plugin, and use it on Android/iOS.

The first one is [Keyframes](https://github.com/facebookincubator/Keyframes), by Facebook. It's the library behind the new Reaction animations on the Facebook App.

There's also [Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android), by AirBnb that looks like it's more powerful.